# Matricial distribution

Tags: vba, algorithm, excel, matrix

I have a list of projects with hours to be consumed, distributed linearly through the months:

```
Hours  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
100    20   20   20   20   20
200    40   40   40   40   40
300    60   60   60   60   60

600    120  120  120  120  120
```

Some projects will end in different months, so it shoudn't mark any hour in the next months (must be 0):

```
Hours  Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov   Dec  End
100    33.3   33.3   33.3   0     0    Oct
200    50     50     50     50    0    Nov
300    60     60     60     60    60   Dec

600    143.3  143.3  143.3  110   60
```

However, we have to keep the proportion of 20% of the sum (20% * 600 = 120. I've put 20% because we have 5 months, but it could be different percentages) on each month, so:

```
Hours  Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov   Dec  End
100    20     30     50     0     0    Oct
200    60     50     30     60    0    Nov
300    40     40     40     60    120  Dec

600    120    120    120    120   120
```

I have a Sudoku-like problem here, where I need to respect the proportion of the column and keep the sum of the line on each project. I've tried in many ways (VBA or functions) to make this distribution, but I've failed so far. I believe someone has crossed with this problem before, so is there a way of doing this distribution programatically? Is there a name for this kind of distribution?

Comment: Just to be clear...you want to put the total in column **A** and the end-month in column **F** and want a method to automatically fill in columns **B** through **E** ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That is correct! It shall respect the end-month, the hours in the line and the percentage of each month!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the image below. Once you have the marginal sums filled in, enter this formula into B2 and fill in the rest of the table (enter it as an array formula with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>):

```
=IF(MATCH($H2,$B$1:$F$1,0)<COLUMNS($B$1:B$1),0,($A2-SUM(C2:$G2))/(SUM(IF(MATCH($H$2:$H$4,$B$1:$F$1,0)<COLUMNS($B$1:B$1),0,$A$2:$A$4))-SUM(IF(MATCH($H$2:$H$4,$B$1:$F$1,0)<COLUMNS($B$1:B$1),0,C$2:$G$4)))*B$5)
```

[image]

The example given will not have a unique solution, so the aim with the above formula is to *balance* the hours by starting at the end and moving backwards in time while applying hours proportionally to how many hours are left on each project. For example, after resolving Dec, the project on row 2 still has 200 hours to allocate and the project on row 3 still has 180 hours to allocate. The formula will therefore apply 120 * 200 / (200 + 180) hours in Nov from the project on row 2 and 120 * 180 / (200 + 180) hours from the project in row 3.

This methodology assumes that all projects start at the same time. If this assumption doesn't hold, VBA would probably be the way to go. I would sort the months by the number of active projects, smallest to largest, then apply the same sort of calculation as here.

Comment: you nailed it! That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot! 
I'll study what you've done here so I can improve my knowledges, I've never used matricial formulas before. 
Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I got your question right, but hopefully yes because it took me quite a lot of time. It actually looks deceptively easy, but is in fact quite tricky.

So let's presume we have this table:

[image]

> Now if I got it right, we basically want to count, how many hours we
>   used up already, and now we want to distribute what we have left
>   depending on the unused (empty) months

So, for example, in Row 3 (100 hours) we don't want to distribute any hours, because we already used up all 100 out of 100 hours

In the next row (4), we want to distribute 115 hours (200-85) to the remaining 2 cells => which would leave us with 57.5 hours per month left on shift

and et cetera...

Under presumption, that's what you want the algorhytm to do:

```
Private Sub divide_time()

Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
Dim hour_dist() As Integer
ReDim hour_dist(1 To 3)

' first we need to learn how many hours total we have available per project
For i = 1 To 3
    With tbl.ListColumns(1)
        hour_dist(i) = .Range(i + 1) ' we store each value into an array per project
    End With
Next i

Dim current As Double
Dim sumof As Double
Dim hours_left As Double
Dim empty_counter As Integer

For i = 1 To 3

    'we reset all of the counters per row
    sumof = 0
    empty_counter = 0

    'looping through all the column values in the row
    For j = 2 To 6
        current = tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, j)
        sumof = sumof + current ' we get a sum of the current values in the row
        If (current = 0) Then 'if there is an empty cell, we keep track of it _
        (so we know into how many cells we can still divide the remaining time)
            empty_counter = empty_counter + 1
        End If
    Next j

    ' so we get how many hours we have left for the project _
    in comparison to  how many  months are free to distribute
    hours_left = (hour_dist(i) - sumof)

    'if we also want to store the info, _ 
    'what month we ended on before we distribute the remaining hours
    If (hours_left = 0) Then
    Select Case empty_counter
        Case 0
            tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Dec"
        Case 1
            tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Nov"
        Case 2
            tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Oct"
        Case 3
            tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Sep"
        Case 4
            tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Aug"
    End Select
    Else
        tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, 7) = "Dec"
    End if

    If (empty_counter <> 0) Then '( we dont want to be dividing by 0 )
    For n = 6 To (6 - empty_counter + 1) Step -1

        'for each month we divide what we have left _
         depending on the % of the months available
        tbl.ListRows(1).Range(i, n) = (hours_left / empty_counter)

    Next n
    End If



' and we loop it for each and every row
Next i

End Sub
```

The resulting table will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't managed to be clear. This is a calendarization of hours for projects, so the total hours are already set and needed to be distributed throughout the months, respecting the proportion of hours determined by the month and the end of the project. See the solution from @jblood94, those matricial formulas are magical.

Comment: Hello, alright, albeit the solution by @jblood94 while elegant, will not work if you have to distribute the time unevenly (if the projects dont start at the same time, which seems like a realistic scenario with differnet projects). I tried being descriptive in my code with comments, so hopefully you should be able to tweak it to your needs. If the starting times are static, then more power to you and simply use jblood94's solution :)

Comment: At this point, all projects are starting the same month, but it's true what you said. I will study both your code and the @jblood94 formula to see if I can mix them together to achieve a final solution. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to think "backwards".
First distribute hours among active projects in month *n* (December).
Deduct these hours from respective project and move to month *n-1*, etc.